# Can't insert arabic text into mysql database using mysql prompt

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, command-line, utf-8, mysqli

I had a local table with arabic values.when exported i got the following query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `type`;
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
 `bs_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `types` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bs_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 
-- Data for table `business_type`
-- 

INSERT INTO `type` (`bs_id`, `types`) VALUES
 ('1', 'صناعة'),
 ('2', 'معارض'),
 ('3', 'أسواق'),
 ('4', 'إستيراد وتوزيع'),
 ('5', 'خدمات'),
 ('6', 'إستشارات'),
 ('7', 'أخرى');
```

I want to create this table on server so i just copied the above query and run it on server terminal.The query works fine but the values in table is showing like ".....".

tried this

```
 SET NAMES utf8;
```

before inserting the values,but failed.I don't have a cpanel installed on server.Command prompt is the only option.

Can anyone help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you can only use the Command prompt, my suggestion is to shift the character set to one that supports Arabic within the mysql client:

I just ran these commands on my laptop at home (Windows 8.1)

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.character_sets where description like '%arabic%';
+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+--------+
| CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME | DESCRIPTION    | MAXLEN |
+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+--------+
| cp1256             | cp1256_general_ci    | Windows Arabic |      1 |
+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from information_schema.global_variables where variable_name like 'version%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME           | VARIABLE_VALUE               |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| VERSION                 | 5.6.21                       |
| VERSION_COMMENT         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| VERSION_COMPILE_MACHINE | x86_64                       |
| VERSION_COMPILE_OS      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Start up the mysql client using [**--default-character-set**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set) like this

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=cp1256
```

In the event you are running on Linux, make sure you run

```
select * from information_schema.character_sets where description like '%arabic%';
```

and make sure you have a character set that support Arabic

**Give it a Try !!!**

There is a nice post in StackOverflow [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588466/491757). It has three nice queries to help inspect your database to make sure data can be saved with the right character set.

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA but before trying i just want to know will this affect any existing content in DB?